# Attach docker to an asp.net core project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2022

i am trying to attach my asp.net core project to a rabbitmq docker previously added in docker desktop when i go to debug/attach to process then do the attachment i have the following error: "failure to launching the debug adapter" and on the console output I have "Program '[102] inet_gethost' terminated with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)." what could have caused this?I added an image of the attachment process[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQhg.png)

I thought it might be my container that wasn't on I reassured myself that it's on but I have the same problem, therefore I can't even think of even running the project because this step does not work yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: here is what my project tree looks like (I will only put the important folders):
in the first project i have a model folder with my model class here is the model code
"namespace EPAFGUOT.Models
{
    public class Assurance
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string designation { get; set; }
        public float prime { get; set; }
        public string risque { get; set; }
    }
}"

Comment: I'm having a little trouble sharing the code because of the number of characters in the input fields, I'm trying to find a way to share the code with you